# How would I get the Fields which are enabled and the position from left

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, splistitem

In my SharePoint list, I have modified the view like this.

[image]

I want to get the 'Display' value and 'Position from Left' value for the fields. Is is possible with CSOM or another way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the below code, it will give you the list of Fields that are in Display in the View and the postiion from left.

```
public static void GetViewDetails()
        {
            ClientContext context = new ClientContext("https://testsite/test");
            List list = context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("ListName");
            context.Load(list);
            context.ExecuteQuery();
            View view = list.Views.GetByTitle("ViewName");

            context.Load(view, v=>v.ViewFields);
            context.ExecuteQuery();

            string fields = view.ViewFields.SchemaXml;
            XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
            xmlDoc.LoadXml("<FieldData>"+fields+"</FieldData>");
            XmlNodeList dataNodes = xmlDoc.SelectNodes("//FieldData");
            //Loading the data to the Dictionary in Position from left,Field Name format
            Dictionary<int,string> data=new Dictionary<int,string>();
            int order=0;
            foreach (XmlNode node in dataNodes)
            {
                foreach (XmlNode childNode in node.ChildNodes)
                {
                    order++;
                    data.Add(order, childNode.Attributes[0].Value);
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ji. I just used `ViewFieldCollection vfc = view.ViewFields;
                for (int i = 0; i < vfc.Count; i++)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("field: " + vfc[i] + " position: " + (i + 1));
                }` instead of using `SchemaXml`.

Comment: But I have one difficulty in this. I couldn't get the correct name of the field. As I analyzed in this, the view contains only 'StaticName' of the field but what exactly required is 'DisplayName'. Still wondering how to get that.

Answer (score 1):

## Another Way

You can get it using REST API. Just send a GET request to the following end point

```
/_api/Web/Lists/GetByTitle('{list name}')/Views/GetByTitle('{view name }')/ViewFields
```

In the response, you should get response like following

```
{
    "d": {
        "__metadata": {
            "id": "Web/Lists/GetByTitle('Customers')/Views/GetByTitle('All Items')/ViewFields",
            "uri": "http://xxx.sharepoint.com/_api/Web/Lists/GetByTitle('Customers')/Views/GetByTitle('All%20Items')/ViewFields",
            "type": "SP.ViewFieldCollection"
        },
        "SchemaXml": "<FieldRef Name=\"LinkTitle\" /><FieldRef Name=\"Multiusers\" /><FieldRef Name=\"ID\" />",
        "Items": {
            "__metadata": {
                "type": "Collection(Edm.String)"
            },
            "results": [
                "LinkTitle",
                "Multiusers",
                "ID"
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

`d.Items.results` array contains your field names. Array index is your position.

**PS:** JavaScript array position starts from 0. So the actual position will be item index plus one.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I haven't tested your code because I am using CSOM only. But seems to be a great way I will try that.